# forced type conversion with parentheses

Tags: c, type-conversion

Today I found something interesting and strange.

The output of the codes below is:

```
410065408
9000000000
```

I found "forced type conversion" with parentheses is wrong.
And I guess `return (long) (a * b)` equals to `return (long) ((int) a * b)`.

The conversion of `410065408`(int) is still `410065408`(long).

Am I right?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = 100000, b = 90000;
  printf("%ld\n%ld\n", product_wrong(a, b), product_right(a, b));
  return 0;
}

long product_wrong(int a, int b)
{
  return (long) (a * b);
}


long product_right(int a, int b)
{
  return (long) a * b;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression `(long) (a * b)`, `(a * b)` is an `int` type. The cast to `long` happens too late and the behaviour of your program is *undefined* as you are overflowing the `int` type on your platform.

`(long)a * b` is grouped as `((long)a) * b`, so `b` is promoted to a `long`.

There's *still* a danger of `long` overflow here on some platforms; consider using a `long long` for portability.

Comment: So is "return (long) a * b;" the only way and the best way to convert type int "a * b" to type long?

Comment: I prefer `return 1l * a * b;`

Comment: ... or `1L` as it is more visually distinctive than `1l`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you.